# Why do we use else if?

Tags: python, c, if-statement, conditional-statements

I just want to know why the use of `else if`? is it just a customary style or does it serve a back-end purpose?

I'm asking because we can just `if, if, if...else` and it would deliver the same result.

Comment: Consider the case of using `if...if` versus `if ... elif` if both conditions are true...

Comment: So far, all of the answers have missed the fact that `if (x == 3) x = 4; else if (x == 4) x = 5; else x = 6;` is different from `if (x == 3) x = 4; if (x == 4) x = 5; else x = 6;`.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is exclusivity. If you have multiple `if` conditions, and each of them are met, they'll *all* fire.

With the else if, the *first* condition that matches will fire in that block.

```
const testStr = "test";

function checkStr(str) {
  if (str == 'test') console.log("It's test");
  if (typeof str == 'string') console.log("It's a string");
  if (str.length == 4) console.log("It's 4 long");
}

function elseCheckStr(str) {
  if (str == 'test') console.log("It's test");
  else if (typeof str == 'string') console.log("This won't run");
  else if (str.length == 4) console.log("This won't run either");
}

checkStr(testStr);
elseCheckStr(testStr);
```

Answer (score 2):

It has an actual purpose. For example:

```py
x = 10
if x > 100:
  print("More than 100")
elif x > 50:
  print("More than 50")
```

will output

```
More than 100
```

but

```py
x = 10
if x > 100:
  print("More than 100")
if x > 50:
  print("More than 50")
```

will output

```
More than 100
More than 50
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not a stupid question, although it's a very basic one.

Consider this:

```
x = 5
if x > 2:
    print(f'{x} is greater than 2')
if x > 3:
    print(f'{x} is greater than 3')
else:
    print(f'{x} is not greater than 2 or 3')
```

And compare to:

```
x = 5
if x > 2:
    print(f'{x} is greater than 2')
elif x > 3:
    print(f'{x} is greater than 3')
else:
    print(f'{x} is not greater than 2 or 3')
```

If you read carefully, you'll see that the first example will print both of the first two lines - you'd use `elif` to avoid that.

That's generally true, you use `elif` instead of a new `if` if you don't want the second `if` to even be executed if the first one is true.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this should answer your question:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/223714/is-there-any-specific-reason-to-use-else-if-clause

TLDR; You're right about if, if, if, else being an option (if you're very specific in your clauses). However it can be a bit messy. Using elif / else if is a better alternative to make code more readable.

Comment: I was writing a comment the same time you were, I literary answered my own question after I saw an example of how messy it would be.

Comment: Don't worry we've all been there :)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the situation. Consider the following code:

```
num = 5
if num > 1:
   print("num > 1")
if num > 2:
   print("num > 2")
if num > 3:
   print("num > 3")
if num > 4:
   print("num > 4")
if num > 5:
   print("num > 5")
else:
   print("num not > 5")
```

You would get the following output:

```
num > 1
num > 2
num > 3
num > 4
num not > 5
```

If you did this instead:

```
num = 5
if num > 1:
   print("num > 1")
elif num > 2:
   print("num > 2")
elif num > 3:
   print("num > 3")
elif num > 4:
   print("num > 4")
elif num > 5:
   print("num > 5")
else:
   print("num not > 5")
```

The output would only be:

```
num > 1
```

The first selection statement would be true, so the rest would be ignored